# Google ad overlaps fixed div?

Tags: html, fixed, ads

I recently started to teach myself web development from scratch and am having trouble.

I created a fixed div for the header of my website using a basic html 5 code. The header works great for the most part when scrolling over content, but once it reached a Google ad placement the ad seems to overlap it and scrolls in front the header instead of behind it. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Even if Matt's answer solved your problem, it's always nice and useful to add more information, like some sample code or an URL to your website. It will help you get useful answers more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see some example code, but to begin with try setting the z-index using CSS on the header so that it is higher than the google ad div.